# Issue with Graphing Points

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, axis

So I have been trying to graph a function for my economics class. My problem is that the "axis" that are created do not match up with actual points; for example, the point (0,5) will not be on the y-axis, it is shifted over.

Here is the code for my graph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[
color= black,
xmin=0, 
xmax=19.5, 
ymin=0, 
ymax=19.5, 
axis equal, 
axis x line=left,
axis y line=left,
disabledatascaling,
xticklabels={}, 
yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
ticks=none,
extra x ticks=0,
extra y ticks=0,
]

\draw (0,5) -- (10,0);

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My issue is not with creating a graph; I only put a simple line to demonstrate that the points are not lining up.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I cannot figure it out at all. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `axis y line=middle`

Answer (score 4):

As David already pointed out in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449600/95441) this is because of the `axis equal` option which changes the axis limits to fit the specified `width` and `height` of the `axis`.

Another alternative would be to use the `axis equal image` key, which changes either the `width` or the `height`.

If you *always* want to be sure that the axis lines are drawn at the zero coordinates, you should use `axis lines=middle` instead of `axis lines=left`, as Henri Menke already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449599/issue-with-graphing-points#comment1129617_449599).

(I also made some other comments to your code in my answer code, which you should have a look at. Just in case you weren't aware of this stuff.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%    % (use this `compat' level or higher so by default TikZ coordinates use
%    %  `axis cs:'. See comments below for more details.)
%    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=19.5,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=19.5,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % replace `axis equal' with `axis equal image'
%        axis equal,
        axis equal image,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%        % (if you want to be sure that the axis lines are drawn at the
%        %  zero coordinates, than you should use `axis lines=middle'.
%        %  Please note that then by default the zero ticklabels are not
%        %  drawn, because in general these would be written on "the other"
%        %  axis line. To make them appear nonetheless you could add
%        %  `hide obscured x ticks=false' (and similar for the y axis), as
%        %  are commented below the next commented option line.)
        axis lines=left,
%            axis lines=middle,
%            hide obscured x ticks=false,
%            hide obscured y ticks=false,
%        % (if you comment `disabledatascaling' you also don't get the desired
%        %  result, because with the default `compat' level TikZ coordinates
%        %  by default don't use the axis coordinate system (`axis cs:'), but
%        %  the tikzpicture coordinate system (`cs:'). ...
%        disabledatascaling,
    ]
        % (... To overcome this issue you could either prepend all TikZ
        %  coordinates by `axis cs:' or use a `compat' value of 1.11 or higher)
        \draw [red,thick] (        0,5) -- (        10,0);
        \draw [green]     (axis cs:0,5) -- (axis cs:10,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will play around with this more, but you are right, I do not know about all of the small details, and I have a lot more control over how my picture looks now! I appreciate the help so much.

Comment: Glad that I could help. If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the `axis equal` line. `axis equal` changes the axis limits automatically in order to make the plot fit in the specified height and width. You can see that it's changing the x-axis by commenting out the `ticks=none` line - the 0 tick mark is not at the y axis.

I recommend removing the `axis equal` line.